# Is there a built-in way in pandas dataframes to include next/previous rows of slice if requested index is between integer index labels?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example dataframe:

```
    value 
ind
1   2.3
3   4.4
5   3.3
7   6.6
```

and then I slice with:

```
df.loc[2:4]
```

Default output is going to be just:

```
3   4.4
```

But I want the upper and lower values included:

```
1   2.3
3   4.4
5   3.3
```

Is there a built-in way without some extra logic?

Comment: You might have got the idea of `.loc[]` wrong. `.loc[]` does not access the column `value`, so it does not act on the values 2.3 and 3.3. It accesses the index based on value. As you are using integers as the index, you are asking for "Select indexes between 2 and 4 (excluding)". As you index consists of 1, 3 and 5, only 3 is a valid selection and will be returned.

Comment: I don't think I got the idea wrong, I want to adapt the default output for my own purposes, see the answer by @snowdd1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: No**

The `.loc[]` method looks for the first index value equal to or larger the start value of the slice, and the reverse for the stop value of the slice.

If you need that extra logic (evaluate if the start value has an exact match, if not, get the next best lower value, and equivalent for the stop value), you have to do that using your own code (at least not pandas built-in, there might be a solution for that in the net already)

Working stub (no exception handling etc, assumes df is ordered by integer index, and fails if hitting first or last row):

```
def loc2(df, start, stop):
    r = df.loc[start:stop]
    if r.index[0]>start:
        start=df.index.to_list()[df.index.to_list().index(r.index[0])-1]
    if r.index[-1]<stop:
        stop=df.index.to_list()[df.index.to_list().index(r.index[-1])+1]
    return df.loc[start:stop]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there's an in-built way for this, but you can get the upper and lower values you want specifying your boundaries and including them in your slice:

```
>>> r = 1
>>> df.loc[2 - r : 4 + r]

Out[75]: 
     value
ind       
1      2.3
3      4.4
5      3.3
```

So by adjusting the `r` you can specify how many next or previous rows to include

**EDIT**: Based on your comments below, try using `iloc` and not `loc`:

Assume this `df`:

```
>>> df

Out[108]: 
     value
ind       
1      2.3
3      4.4
5      3.3
7      6.6
11     7.4
21     6.7
33     7.8
34     2.3
35     6.9


# Boundary
>>> r = 2

# Using loc
>>> df.loc[2 - r : 4 + r]

Out[111]: 
     value
ind       
1      2.3
3      4.4
5      3.3

# Using iloc
>>> df.iloc[2 - r : 4 + r]

Out[112]: 
     value
ind       
1      2.3
3      4.4
5      3.3
7      6.6
11     7.4
21     6.7
```

Comment: that's quite a nice solution assuming the jumps are a consistent size, I'm not sure I can guarantee that will be the case though.

Comment: Do you mean 'jumps' based on your index numbers? For example your index could've been 1,5,9,13 etc?

Comment: I mean it could be 1,3,5,9,11,15, I can't guarantee regular spacing.

Comment: Okay got it. But you will always know how many rows above and below you will want to return back? If yes, there's an easy fix to address that.

Comment: yes, I think the answer by @snowdd1 looks pretty nice for my particular case.

Comment: I think what you need is to use ```iloc``` and not ```loc```. Of course use the answer that suits your needs.

Comment: In fact I don't think so, my example was very simple though and didn't include a lot of extra information about the use case. In practice the solution needs to be a bit more general, appreciate your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the index, you could use `shift()`

```py
s = slice(2,4)
df_ = pd.concat([df['value'].shift(1).loc[s], df['value'].loc[s], df['value'].shift(-1).loc[s]])
```

```
# print(df_)

ind
3    2.3
3    4.4
3    3.3
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: In fact in this case the index is meaningful